# How to remove xml attribute value from logstash and pass to elasticserach?

Tags: logstash

Here is the xml file, Tag test-methode contains name=reEnterURL is repeat with each test. i dont want to pass this value to elastic search. Only status=pass name=newProfile is required to pass elastic search.

```
 </test-method> 
    <test-method status="PASS" signature="reEnterURL()[pri:0, instance:testSuite.DriverScript_Transformation@6fc757]" name="reEnterURL" is-config="true" duration-ms="1107" started-at="2015-12-30T15:55:24Z" finished-at="2015-12-30T15:55:26Z">
      <reporter-output>
      </reporter-output>
    </test-method> 
    <test-method status="PASS" signature="newProfile()[pri:0,instance:testSuite.DriverScript_Transformation@6fc757]" name="newProfile" duration-ms="818999" started-at="2015-12-30T15:55:26Z" finished-at="2015-12-30T16:09:05Z">
      <reporter-output>
      </reporter-output>
    </test-method>
```

Here is the conf file:

```
input {
file {
path=>["file-path/testng-result.xml"]
start_position =>"beginning"
type =>suitefile
  }
 }

 filter
 { 
 if[type]=="suitefile"
 {
 xml
 {

 source =>"message"

 remove_namespaces => "true"   


 xpath => ["//test-method/@name","Name",
  "//test-method/@status", "Status"] 
  store_xml => false

    }
 }
}

output {
 stdout { codec => rubydebug}
 elasticsearch_http{
 host => "ip address"   
  }
 }
```